# Android Espresso insists button is not visible

Tags: android, android-espresso

I'm trying to click on a button on a dialog with Espresso.  On a tall screen the button is displayed and it's fine.  On a smaller screen, even if I swipe up and the button is displayed, the click fails:

```
Action will not be performed because the target view does not match one or more of the following constraints:
at least 90 percent of the view's area is displayed to the user.
```

Here's the relevant code:

```
swipeUp(R.id.scroll);
onView(withText("OK"))
                .inRoot(isDialog())
                .check(matches(isDisplayed()))
                .perform(click());
```

I put a breakpoint after the swipe and took a screen shot:

[image]

As you can see, the button is fully visible.  I've tried matching the button in various ways:

```
onView(withText("Ok")
onView(withText("ok")
onView(withText("OK"))
                .inRoot(isDialog())
                .check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

This is what the test recorder wrote:

```
onView(
                allOf(withId(android.R.id.button1), withText("OK"),
                        childAtPosition(
                                childAtPosition(
                                        withClassName(is("android.widget.ScrollView")),
                                        0),
                                3)));
```

I also tried just using pressBack() but that doesn't close the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

If the button is in a `ScrollView`, then try to perform with a [ViewActions.scrollTo()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/action/ViewActions.html#scrollTo()):

```
onView(withText("OK"))
    .inRoot(isDialog())
    .perform(scrollTo(), click());
```

Comment: I think I tried that but I will try it again if I get back to this project.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to define a click action which will handle the scrolling when neccessary so you wont have to make unnecessary scrollTo action each time.

```
 fun clickViewWithText(text: String) {
            try {
                onView(withText(text)).perform(click())
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                onView(withText(text)).perform(scrollTo(), click())
            }
        }
```

You can also generalize this and write

```
fun clickView(matcher: Matcher<View>) {
            try {
                onView(matcher).perform(click())
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                onView(matcher).perform(scrollTo(), click())
            }
        }
```